# Ajax request from overridden component of joomla template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm new guy in joomla and i was searching for the answer a lot of time, but didn't get the result. I have my template in joomla 3.4.5 and i have overridden component com_content and category inside it. I made my file blog.php where i output my calendar. The problem is to send ajax changing month by clickng proper button. There is an error, when i'm trying to send ajax. Seems like joomla bans direct request. I read many articles, like how to use ajax in modules and components, but there is no advice how to use it in overriden component. Please give me detailed answer for my problem.

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $document->addScript('/space/media/media/js/mainscript.js');
```

i used that code to include my scriptfile in blog.php

```
function getAjaxData()
  {
      echo  'login: ' .$_REQUEST['month'] . '; password: ' . $_REQUEST['year'];
      exit;
  }
```

created method to handle my ajax request in blog.php

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict()
j(document).ready(function(){

    j('#next').click(function(){

        var month = j(this).data('month');
        var year = j(this).data('year');

        if(month == 12){
            year +=1;
            month = 1;
        }
        else{
            month++;
        }

        j.post("/space/templates/forte/")

        j.ajax({
         url: "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&task=getAjaxData&format=raw",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
                month: month,
                year: year

         },
         success: function(data){ 
           j('#calendar_wrap').html(data);
          }
        });

        console.log('month: '+month+' year: '+year);
    })

    j('#prev').click(function(){

        var month = j(this).data('month');
        var year = j(this).data('year');

        if(month == 1){
            year -=1;
            month = 12;
        }
        else{
            month--;
        }

        j.ajax({
         url: "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&task=getAjaxData&format=raw",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
                month: month,
                year: year

         },
         success: function(data){ 
            j('#calendar_wrap').html(data);
          }
        });

        console.log('month: '+month+' year: '+year);
    })
});
```

mainscript.js, included in blog.php

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

here is the error outputted to browser console

Comment: What error are you getting? Show us your ajax code.

Comment: On a side topic - Please update to Joomla 3.4.6 immediately. It fixes a very important security issue.

Comment: On topic - I second what @Epodax said. We can't help unless you show us your code and errors that are being thrown. Giving a detailed answer as you've requested would involve mind reading/magic

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm using this website for a long time, but this is my first ask here, because it is the first time for years when i can't solve my problem, using google. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem with that error by putting that method:

```
public function getAjaxData()
{

}
```

In file: `/site/components/com_content/controller.php`

but, i have one more problem now.
In that method my calendar outputs again, but now we have new values, send by ajax. The code below:

```
public function getAjaxData()
  {

        JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript('/space/media/media/js/mainscript.js');

      function days_in_month($month, $year) 
      { 
        // calculate number of days in a month 
        return $month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year % 400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31); 
      }

      // get number of days in needed month

      $currentYear = date('Y');
      $currentMonth = date('n');
      if(isset($_REQUEST['year']))
        $currentYear = $_REQUEST['year'];
      if(isset($_REQUEST['month']))
        $currentMonth = $_REQUEST['month'];


      $rusmonth = array('Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь');

      $dayofmonth = days_in_month($currentMonth, $currentYear);
      // count for days in month
      $day_count = 1;

      // 1. first week
      $num = 0;
      for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
      {
        // get day of week
        $dayofweek = date('w',
                          mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonth, $day_count, $currentYear));
        // format our values to 1-monday, 6-saturday
        $dayofweek = $dayofweek - 1;
        if($dayofweek == -1) $dayofweek = 6;

        if($dayofweek == $i)
        {
          // if numbers of week are equal,
          // put values into array $week
          $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
          $day_count++;
        }
        else
        {
          $week[$num][$i] = "";
        }
      }

      // 2. other weeks of month
      while(true)
      {
        $num++;
        for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
          $week[$num][$i] = $day_count;
          $day_count++;
          // if we got the end of the month exit from loop
          if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
        }

        if($day_count > $dayofmonth) break;
      }

      // 3. output array $week

      echo '<div> <span id="prev" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'"><</span> '.$rusmonth[$currentMonth-1].' <span id="next" data-month="'.$currentMonth.'" data-year="'.$currentYear.'">></span>  </div>';
      echo '<div id="calendar_wrap">';
        echo '<table border=1>';
        echo '<tr>
                    <th>ПН</th>
                    <th>ВТ</th>
                    <th>СР</th>
                    <th>ЧТ</th>
                    <th>ПТ</th>
                    <th>СБ</th>
                    <th>ВС</th>
                 </tr>';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($week); $i++)
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          for($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)
          {
            if(!empty($week[$i][$j]))
            {

              if($j == 5 || $j == 6) 
                   echo "<td><font color=red>".$week[$i][$j]."</font></td>";
              else echo "<td>".$week[$i][$j]."</td>";
            }
            else echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
        } 
        echo "</table>";
      echo '</div>';
    exit;
  }
```

in that method i can't add my script again to get new month.
So there are two ways for me as I see:
 1. make my method that way, so he become something like a bridge between blog.php and ajax. There will be no outputs.

2. Find a way, how could i add script to controller and make double code.

The problem is, that i have no idea, how realize both of it in Joomla...
Of course i prefer 1st variant.